# How to add marker with different images in mapbox at runtime?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I have a problem, I want to add different images on a marker at runtime.

I can basically add images in style and then I have to load the map to add a marker with a different image.

This is how I add images in mapbox right now

```
mapView.getMapAsync {
    it.setStyle(Style.Builder().fromUrl("mapbox://styles/{user}/{mapid}")) { style ->
        // Add the marker image to map
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_user_one_round)?.let { img ->
            style.addImageAsync("key", img)
        }
}
```

Mapbox should be able to show images or render it at runtime on a different marker.

For example, **snap chat** using it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the older Marker API, you can simply add markers via `mapView.addMarkers()`. You can customize them at runtime with `MarkerOptions()` or `MarkerViewOptions()`. More on markers [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/annotations/#markers).

On the other hand you could use a *SymbolLayer* to provide your custom markers, allowing more customization and custom logic for styling (and performance). I recommend reading [this](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/data-driven-styling/#layers).

A third option would be using the new Annotation Plugin, that is mostly similar to using *Layers* directly, but with more convenience and less need to write boilerplate code. Some examples [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/annotation/) and [in the Github repo](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/testapp/activity/annotation).